# Xcode's dispatch_after causes double to int64_t conversion warning

Tags: c, grand-central-dispatch

Xcode's `dispatch_after` template

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
double delayInNanoSeconds = delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInNanoSeconds);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
});
```

causes the following warning

> Implicit conversion turns floating-point number into integer: 'double' to 'int64_t' (aka 'long long')

because

`delayInNanoSeconds` is converted from a `double` to an `int64_t` implicitly

How bad is this?

Comment: Can you post the code that Xcode is generating? This will help in case it changes in future Xcode releases.

Comment: If that template is from Xcode and it produces that warning, then file a bug, please.

Comment: Radarred http://openradar.appspot.com/11738695

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you’ve converted the time from seconds (expressed in `delayInSeconds`) to nanoseconds (expressed in `delayInNanoSeconds`), you don’t need the extra precision of a `double` and it’s safe to convert to a `long long`. You can cast it in the call to `dispatch_time()`:

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
double delayInNanoSeconds = delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC;

dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                                        (int64_t)delayInNanoSeconds);

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){});
```

This should cause the warning to go away. Alternatively you could change the type of `delayInNanoSeconds`.